# Problems with Frapi-Framework

Tags: server, debian, internal-server-error, frapi

I'm trying to set up Frapi on an Debian 9.1 Server.
Not every step from "http://frapi.github.io/installing/" did work.
Since days getting only this answer:

> "Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Please
>   contact the server administrator at admin@api.frapi to inform them of
>   the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just
>   before this error. More information about this error may be available
>   in the server error log.
>
> Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at 141.28.11.40 Port 80"

Someone worked already with this Framework and can tell me where I did wrong?